# Google Cloud Load Balancer: Error when creating serverless network endpoint group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm running into a new error when trying to provision a load balancer with a serverless network endpoint group pointing to a cloud function. It appears the resource name for the function doesn't pass the regex check. I've successfully deployed this same service in the past on another project.

I've tried multiple names for the function to no avail.

Error:

`Invalid value for field 'resource.cloudFunction.function': 'projects/madeup-project/locations/us-central1/functions/madeup-function'. Must be a match of regex '(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[-_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)'`

This error appears when trying to provision the load balancer. I suspect it has to do with the internal resource name not passing the regex check due to the "/"s in the path.

Details of load balancer config:

- HTTP(S) Load Balancing
- "From Internet to my VMs"
- Backend service: Create backend service. Type: Serverless Network Endpoint Group. Assigned cloud function to Serverless NEG.
- Frontend: HTTPS w/ Static IP and Google-Managed Cert

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: Update: I was able to find a new open bug in the Google issues tracker which pertains to my problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187890152

Comment: The field fails because the string is too long. What API are you calling? More details are required.

Comment: I understand that is with the UI. Did you try to create your serverless NEG by API? and then to use it in your Load balancer?